# Zuul dropping the added headers for few requests while making asynchronous requests from Angular

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have Zuul gateway as proxy between Angular app and our micro services. I have created a zuul filter to add few headers for every request.

```
@Component
public class RoutesAuthenticationFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "route";
    }
    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Object run() {
         ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();              
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("principal", principal);
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("customerheader", String.valueOf("testheader"));

return null;
}
```

This has been working for every request I made from postman.

I started seeing it is not adding/dropping these headers for the requests made to services through gateway from Angular app.

When I look at the log for headers in the request after adding them I see request contains the added headers are present for all requests

```
Headers from the requet after adding them all: { principal=john123, x-forwarded-host=localhost:8080, x-forwarded-proto=http, x-forwarded-prefix=/application-management, x-forwarded-port=8080, customerheader=testheader, x-forwarded-for=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1}
```

But when I print them in the service, they are missing for few requests

```
2018-08-17 11:23:47.709  INFO [application-management,56a2962a54770966,56a2962a54770966,false] 10952 --- [nio-9090-exec-9] c.f.c.v.d.c.i.RequestInterceptor         : Entered request interceptor
customer header from request: testheader
principal from req: john123
2018-08-17 11:23:47.713  INFO [application-management,058aad714328a61f,058aad714328a61f,false] 10952 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] c.f.c.v.d.c.i.RequestInterceptor         : Entered request interceptor
customer header from request: null
principal from req: null
```

In the above output, headers are missing for one request and present for one request.

These two requests are made asynchronously from Angular app.

I do not see this problem if I make these two calls one in another, means if I make one call and wait for the response and make the next one then it is not missing headers

Comment: why is this  not a pre-filter?

Comment: and how are u getting these headers , can u post complete code.

Comment: @IndraneelBende I have raised this issue here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3149

Comment: Okay I will take a look over the weekend